# How to get width and height of the nearest clipping plane

Tags: opengl, 3d, jogl

I was wondering whether it is possible to get the width and height of the near clipping plane in jogl or opengl. I need it in order to convert from a pixel in the screen to the world coordinate on the near clipping plane. I'm currently not using glOrtho and I can't use glUnProject because I am implementing it in a library independent from jogl and opengl.

Comment: You can simply store the values that you pass to glFrustum, gluPerspective or glOrtho. If you can't do that, you can get the projection matrix but you still need to use JOGL and then your library can't be independent of it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently using gluPerspective, but I don't know how to get the width and height from it. So like you said, I'm using the projection matrix at the moment (is working, but was wondering you can do the same with gluPerspective). The library is independent, in the sense that it doesn't depend on the functions of jogl and opengl. So you can still pass matrices and values from a java program using jogl to the functions in the library.

Comment: The OpenGL manual clearly explains what gluPerspective does and the content of the current matrix after its call: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml